# Прием body от POST запроса

Tags: java, android, request, post

Доброго времени суток!

Есть связь между устройством и сервером посредством PHP. 
С устройства я отправляю файл на сервер, который успешно обрабатывается в PHP и сохраняется. Проблема в том, что PHP еще кидает мне в body данные (будь то числа или даже JSON, но не хедары). Вот как мне этот ответ принять?

Ниже код, которым я отправляю данные:

```
   int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
               byte[] buffer;
               int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

               try
               {
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

               URL url = new URL(urlServer);
               connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

               connection.setDoInput(true);
               connection.setDoOutput(true);
               connection.setUseCaches(false);

               connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

               connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

               outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
               inputStream = new DataInputStream (connection.getInputStream());

               outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
               outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);

               outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

               while (bytesRead > 0)
               {
               outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);                
               }

               outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

               fileInputStream.close();
               outputStream.flush();
               outputStream.close();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {

               }
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Связь у вас между устройством и сервером устанавливается посредсвтом протокола HTTP. Что на другой стороне, PHP, Perl или Java, в общем случае неважно. Есть только запрос и ответ.

Судя по вашему вопросу, вы не знаете как обработать ответ. Но непонятно, что именно вы не знаете: формат ответа (т.е. что именно возвращает сервер) или как обработать ответ сервера посредством Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло решение:

```
public static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }
```

Ответ отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161